# How to rearrange the binary image pixel in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

currently im involved in a project where, i have a binary (halftoned) lena image, in which i applied below "randperm" function to permute the image.

```
 wm_image = reshape(halftoned(randperm(numel(halftoned))),size(halftoned));
```

Now , I want to recover the original halftone image. 
If anybody can help with the matlab code?

Comment: Any algorithmic ideas on how you want to recover the image? Do you have prior knowledge (the encoding permutation) or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the random permutation in order to "invert" it.
So the permutation is done:

```
rp = randperm(numel(halftoned)); %// save the permutation
wm_image = reshape( hlaftoned( rp ), size(halftoned) );
```

And the reconstruction

```
img(rp) = wm_image;
img = reshape( img, size(halftoned) );
```

---

Explaining `img(rp)=wm_image`:
Suppose you have `a` a 1-by-2 vector. The command

```
a = [4,5];
```

basically assigns 4 to `a(1)` and 5 to `a(2)`, that is, it is a short hand for

```
a([1,2]) = [4,5];
```

Now, you can see there is a mapping that tells Matlab where to put the right-hand-side elements in the left-hand-side matrix.
You can change this mapping:

```
a([2,1]) = [5,4];
```

Will result with the same `a` but it is done differently.

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thanks it works now. I have a doubt like in reconstruction part, why it is `img(rp) = wm_image;`.what it does ?